# Unable to record video using this code base on python open cv

Tags: python, opencv

Trying to record a video using opencv in python, i have used videowrite() method to record to record a video but i show the error. This error shows the 'an integer is required (got type noneType)'. Need a solution for this error.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import cv2

filename = 'video.avi'
frames_per_sec = 24.0
my_res = '720p'

def change_res(cap,width,height):
    cap.set(3,width)
    cap.set(4,height)

STD_DIMENSIONS= {
    "480p": (640, 480),
    "720p": (1280, 720),
    "1080p": (1920, 1080),
    "4k": (3840, 2160),
}
def get_dims(cap, res = '1080p'):
    width, height = STD_DIMENSIONS['480p']
    if res in STD_DIMENSIONS:
        width, height = STD_DIMENSIONS[res]
        change_res(cap,width,height)
        return width,height
VIDEO_TYPE = {
    'avi' : cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
    'mp4' : cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'),
}

def get_video_type(filename):
    filename, ext  = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext in VIDEO_TYPE:
        return VIDEO_TYPE[ext]
        return VIDEO_TYPE['avi'] 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
dims = get_dims(cap,res=my_res)
video_type_cv2 = get_video_type(filename)

out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,video_type_cv2,frames_per_sec,dims)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitkey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video.py", line 40, in <module>
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename,video_type_cv2,frames_per_sec,dims)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback
```

Comment: The `get_video_type` function returns `None` when the extension is not one of `avi` or `mp4`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `os.path.splitext` in `get_video_type`.

```
# filename = 'video.avi'
filename, ext  = os.path.splitext(filename)
# Now filename = 'video' , and ext = '.avi'
```

You are expecting `ext = 'avi'` which is not handled in `get_video_type` and returns `None`. Here is the [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to doc of function.